# How to list workshop presentations on a CV when circumstances change?

Tags: conference, cv, workshop

This might be a bit of an unusual situation. I was accepted to a workshop as a solo authored abstract, but a situation arose in which I was unable to attend. However, the organizer allowed for my colleague and myself to combine our presentations since we work on similar research. What would be the best way to list this on my CV? Just list the final presentation, e.g.,

> Colleague and Myself. "Joint presentation on cool research subject."
>   NSF Workshop, 2019.

or should I list the original abstract which appeared the proceedings, e.g.,

> Myself. "Cool research project." presented by Colleague as part of
>   Colleague and  Myself. "Joint presentation on cool research subject."
>   NSF Workshop, 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend option 1, followed by a parenthetical:

Colleague and Myself. "Joint presentation on cool research subject." NSF Workshop, 2019. (abstracted as: Myself, Cool research Topic)

The joint presentation is the real presentation.  Not the abstract.  Consider that you would not list an abstract for a meeting where you bailed entirely.  (Well I hope you would not consider abstracts for papers/presentations not done at all to be worthy of listing.  Otherwise, send out 50 abstracts--woot!)

Answer (score 2):

I think the second option is better since the abstract appeared in the proceedings. Otherwise, the first would probably be best. People searching will likely be looking for the abstract as accepted and published.